# how can i find correlation between very few items in dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Hi i am new to dataframe, please help me resolve this.

My dataframe1 looks like this (It has itemID and Item name), i only have 7 items

```
  itemID   ItemName
    1        abc
    2        fds
    3        btbtr
    4        gerhet
    5        dfhkwjfn
    6        adaf
    7        jdkj
```

My Dataframe2 looks like this:

which has userID, and itemID, here i have 20k users and each user has a itemid in front of it(can be multiple)

```
  userId     itemID
   23213       2
   31267       3
   52144       1
   52144       2
   87467       6
```

how can i find item- item correlation between the items?
I want that item1 is highly correlated with item3 and item6

i tried corrwith() but all i get is NaN.

please help me find this, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I can think of. Might be crude, but here we go.

1. Remove all users which have only 1 item in front of them
2. Now you only have users with multiple items.
3. Make a note of the count of co-occurrence of items. i.e. make a data frame of sort
   item-item : count

> 1-2 : 50
>
> 3-5 : 35

and so on. Now after getting all one on one correlations normalize the count values between 0-1 and you have your correlation between all items.

Hope it helps!

Comment: that thing can be removed afterwards, those who have correlation of 1 can be removed, please try with a example, i don't understand